# Does Logging in on VS Code account using Github Account other than normal email id makes any difference?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-actions

I have noticed my Untracked/Modified appears in front of my files while working on a project, and also I created repo on Github after full completion of my project but it showed the days changes were commited before, like it does when we normally create and push code side by side ?

[dates code was pushed earlier, though the repo was created after completion of whole project, and was pushed at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI5VR.png)
[modified message, without git init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYwZl.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.